# How display image in option of select tag in cordova app?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap

I have a Cordova app. I am getting an image from API in base 64 format. And I want to display that image as icon in the select option. Is is possible to this in cordova?

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck with this problem at the time.

the only solution I found is to create or use an existing component that looks like select input but uses images for image selector.

You can find more info here:

https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/03/12/selecting-multiple-images-in-a-phonegapcordova-app